# Can't run JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, fxml

I can't run JavaFX application. I just want to store some data into table and see it.But only I got mistake someone please help me.
**this is my controller class**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person,Integer> number;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person,String> name;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Person,String> surname;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            table = new TableView<>();
            number = new TableColumn<>();
            name = new TableColumn<>();
            surname = new TableColumn<>();

            number.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("id"));
            name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
            surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("surname"));
            ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person(1,"fa","fafe"));
            table.setItems(data);
            table.getColumns().addAll(number,name,surname);



    }
}
```

but I'm getting following errors which I get from terminal I gave every id to my components

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/1927950199.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onEditStart='#click', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/D:/work%20proyeqt%20immidetely/WorkWithTable/out/production/WorkWithTable/sample/sample.fxml:15

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:606)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:766)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2817)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2526)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/355529278.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/2000304245.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/225942701.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2051067688.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/517043427.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

this is error just keeping occur in my terminal.what it might be wrong please help me to solve this. I just want to store some data into my table that's it and see the result in application.

Comment: You have defined a click method to be called for onEditStart for some control, either remove it from the fxml, or create a public method called "click" in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

The important line in your error message is this one:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onEditStart='#click', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/D:/work%20proyeqt%20immidetely/WorkWithTable/out/production/WorkWithTable/sample/sample.fxml:15
```

This means that there is an error on line 15 of sample.fxml, specifically where it says `onEditStart='#click'`. Either it can't resolve 'onEditStart' or click() isn't a function in the controller.